# .class path api java

Tags: java, applet, classpath

I would like to insert an API java into a web page.

Even with such an easy code:

> ```
> applet code =
> 'Ejs.Simulations._apps._examples.HVmin'
>
> archive = 'Ejs/Simulations/_apps/_examples/HVmin/hVmin.jar',
>
> width = 300, 
> height = 300 />
> ```

I get this error:

```
cargar: clase Ejs.Simulations._apps._examples.HVmin not found.
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Ejs.Simulations._apps._examples.HVmin
at sun.plugin2.applet.Applet2ClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadCode(Unknown Source)
at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2Manager.createApplet(Unknown Source)
at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2Manager$AppletExecutionRunnable.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: open HTTP connection failed:http://localhost/blanca/Ejs/Simulations/_apps/_examples/HVmin.class
at sun.plugin2.applet.Applet2ClassLoader.getBytes(Unknown Source)
at sun.plugin2.applet.Applet2ClassLoader.access$000(Unknown Source)
at sun.plugin2.applet.Applet2ClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
... 7 more
Excepción: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Ejs.Simulations._apps._examples.HVmin
```

I don't know where to put HVmin.class, I have tryed in differents paths with the same result.

The file HVmin.class is in this path:
`C:\xampp\htdocs\blanca\Ejs\Simulations\_apps\_examples\HVmin`

Any help, please?

Thanks in advance

Comment: <applet code =
    'Ejs.Simulations._apps._examples.HVmin'

    archive = 'Ejs/Simulations/_apps/_examples/HVmin/hVmin.jar',

    width = 300, 
    height = 300 />

Esta es la etiqueta HTML que incluí en la página.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just put that class in the .jar file with the rest of the applet.